# how to produce output with Texnic center 2.02?

Tags: installing, texniccenter

I installed TXCSetup_2.02Stable_x64 and basic miktex-2.9.5105-x64 in my computer. The installation was successful. But when I tried to build a project I already made with my previous version TXCSetup_1StableRC1 with output pdf, it didn't show the output instead it says "Cannot execute the command."
Could anyone please help me with this problem. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open TeXnicCenter.
2. Press ALT+F7 followed by ALT+W, you will see the following dialog window.

   [image]
3. Press the ellipsis, you will see the following.

   [image]
4. Select the folder in which the (La)TeX binary compilers exist and then confirm by pressing OK.
5. Confirm until all dialog windows get closed.
6. Done, you are ready to work with LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really help me. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Xrylche: Please accept this answer by pressing the check mark button on the left. Optionally vote it up once by pressing the up arrow on the left.

Comment: I am not sure, that the OP will see a window, where he/she can select the binary folder for TeX Live, because as stated in question he/she has installed MiKTeX. ;-) (I noticed point 4 …)