# Beamer.cls Error - How to install beamer

Tags: beamer, installing, document-classes

I installed TeXnicCenter Version 2.02 Stable (64 bit). I wanted to make `beamer` file for my thesis proposal. I already have my sample `beamer`, but when I run it, 3 errors occurred. It says

> "Latex Error: File `beamer.cls' not found"

I really need to `beamer`. Please help me. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have TeX installed? TeXnicCenter is just a front-end isn't it?

Comment: I already installed texniccenter 2.02. What do you mean by a front end?

Comment: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: Still dont get it

Comment: TeXnicCenter is just a TeX **editor**. For **compiling** the files you write with it you also need a TeX distribution.

Comment: Oh, now I see [how to produce output with Texnic center 2.02?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155984) So, you have a basic MiKTeX installation. Read question and answers, and linked questions and answers: [LaTeX packages: automatic versus manual installation, and related issues](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111125).